# grafana datasource max data points

Tags: plugins, grafana

Developing a Grafana datasource plugin is there a way to change max number of datapoints returned to panels?

Request object passed to **datasource.query** function is like below:

```
{
  "range": { "from": "2015-12-22T03:06:13.851Z", "to": "2015-12-22T06:48:24.137Z" },
  "interval": "5s",
  "targets": [
    { "refId": "B", "target": "upper_75" },
    { "refId": "A", "target": "upper_90" }
  ],
  "format": "json",
  "maxDataPoints": 2495 //decided by the panel
}
```

As per code comment (from [docs](http://docs.grafana.org/plugins/developing/datasources/)) `maxDataPoints` is decided by the panel.

No way to override this value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable `maxDataPoints` in query options with this setting in `plugin.json`:

```
"queryOptions": {
   "maxDataPoints": true
},
```

This feature is not documented...